# How to offset border image from edge of element?

Tags: html, css

I have a bottom border image which should be a few (say 3) pixels lower than the actual edge of the element.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
<style>
h1 { background-color: green;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 13px;
    border-image:url("data:image/png;base64,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") 1 1 13 1 repeat;
}
</style>

<h1>How to get a border image offset from the edge of the box?</h1>

<p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet tenderloin drumstick ribeye filet mignon t-bone beef ribs. Tri-tip venison turkey salami drumstick chicken pastrami. Frankfurter pork jowl ball tip tail.</p>
```

Or see JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BDbX2/1/.

How can I get for the border-image to be a little bit lower, so that the green background of the element doesn't peek out from behind the border-image?

Here is a screenshot showing more of what I'm looking for:

[image: Here is a screenshot showing more of what I'm looking for]

Note that above the border, the green is visible and unbroken. But I don't want the green to appear at all below the border.

I'm using Firefox; naturally I'd prefer a solution which worked in multiple (latest version) browsers.

Comment: i am not sure but do want something like http://jsfiddle.net/BhxsZ/

Comment: if you can add a mocked figure of what exactly you want.

Comment: @NullPointer - Adding 3px padding to the bottom doesn't move the border-image downwards.  I'll post a "desired" screenshot momentarily.

Comment: This might sound lame, but wouldn't it be easier to just fill in the bottom 3 pixels of your border image with white? Is there a reason the bottom of the border needs to remain transparent?

Comment: @TracyFu - For flexibility reasons.  Suppose this element is over something with a varied background?  Suppose I just want to change the color in the future?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I'm a fan of pseudo-elements so I would be inclined to use @Gaby's solution. Will keep looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
border-image-outset
```

The amount by which the border image area extends beyond the border box

Checkout the following sites for browser support.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image-outset.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-image-outset

Comment: When implemented into my demo (http://jsfiddle.net/sbcy2/), `border-image-outset: 4px;` is very clean and elegant.

Comment: I should know by now to test things. I looked into this property, but information I found online indicated it was not supported by any browsers, so I did not even try it. Apparently support has changed. Good find.

Comment: This worked in every browser in which my original demo worked.  ;)

Comment: @KatieK: So all browsers supporting `border-image`?

Comment: @ScottS - My demo failed in Opera and Safari (Win), so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
h1 {    
    background-color: green;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:7px; // padding enough to cover the upper part of the border with color
    margin-bottom:6px; // margin + padding should match the height of the border
}
h1:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:-7px; // should match padding-bottom of h1
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 13px;
    border-image:url("data:image/png;base64,...") 1 1 13 1 repeat;
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/BDbX2/7/

Comment: I like your solution (I would have offered it had you not). However, just in case the pseudo elements were needed for something else, I did come up with another solution.

Answer (score 5):

### If a pseudo element is needed for something else

Personally, I like both I29's `border-image-outset` property solution (though only supported in two browsers as of this writing) and secondly Gaby's pseudo element solution as the code is clean and short. ***However, for Gaby's, if you need the pseudo element for something else***, then you can use a gradient background with a small transparent strip at the bottom and the `background-origin: border-box` set. [**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BDbX2/21/). Adding this CSS (only tested in Firefox 17 and Chrome 23):

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(41,154,11,1) 0%, rgba(41,154,11,1) 90%, rgba(41,154,11,0) 91%, rgba(41,154,11,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(41,154,11,1)), color-stop(90%,rgba(41,154,11,1)), color-stop(91%,rgba(41,154,11,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(41,154,11,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(41,154,11,1) 0%,rgba(41,154,11,1) 90%,rgba(41,154,11,0) 91%,rgba(41,154,11,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(41,154,11,1) 0%,rgba(41,154,11,1) 90%,rgba(41,154,11,0) 91%,rgba(41,154,11,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(41,154,11,1) 0%,rgba(41,154,11,1) 90%,rgba(41,154,11,0) 91%,rgba(41,154,11,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(41,154,11,1) 0%,rgba(41,154,11,1) 90%,rgba(41,154,11,0) 91%,rgba(41,154,11,0) 100%); /* W3C */

background-origin: border-box;
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading your problem and reading on the css3 `border-image` property I didn't find any proper solution for a css3 property, so I just created an image if no one has a solution on the `border-image` property.

I have added below rule on h1 tag :

```
 h1{
    background: url("http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/ekzlrnp7tsnxx0uner.png") repeat-x scroll 0 47px green;

/* reset css rules are same as provided in question */
    }
```

**Note:** According to this technique you may not face any issues while changing background color from green to red or any other color.

Here is the solution of the above problem. see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BDbX2/24/)

For Full View: http://jsfiddle.net/BDbX2/24/embedded/result/

Please let me know if any suggestion for me or any enhancement in idea.

Screen shot for visibility:

[image]

Comment: Your solution may allow background on the `h1` to change color, but it does not allow for background of the `body` (or whatever element the `h1` is residing in) to be anything other than white without changing your image (and even then, if the background were not a _solid_ color, it would be impossible to match your added background to what is behind the `h1`). So your solution is useful under certain conditions, but not very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Add div around the h1 tag and give border to div.

**HTML**

```
<div> 
 <h1>How to get a border image offset from the edge of the box?</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
      border: solid transparent;
        border-width: 0 0 13px;
        border-image:url(..) 1 1 13 1 repeat;
        }
    h1
      {    background-color: green; }​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BDbX2/4/)**

---

If you want the green color to be filled behind the border image then add `background-color: green;` to div as well

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/BDbX2/5/)**

---

If you need space between paragraph and the border image then add `margin-bottom:8px` to div style

Comment: Above the border, I would like the green to be visible and unbroken.  But I don't want the green to appear at all below the border.

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing change the border-image color to green?

If so, then perhaps `background-clip` may be what you're looking for: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-origin-and-background-clip/

I've updated your demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/BDbX2/9/

Comment: Having to specify the border-color removes some of the flexibility that I'm aiming for.  Also, your demo has some white bits between the border image and the end of the element (in FF, anyway).

Comment: Yea thats why i was asking about changing the border-image to green, because background-clip makes the background end at the boundary of where the border starts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `border-image-outset` css style in `h1` at the end (note it should be after the `border-image` entry as shown below:

```
h1
{
background-color: green;
border: solid transparent;
border-width: 0 0 13px;
border-image:url("data:image/png;base64,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") 1 1 13 1 repeat;
border-image-outset: 0px 0px 3px 0px; 
}​
```

Here is the jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/rupesh_kokal/BDbX2/37/

For more information on the style and browser support refer to:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-image-outset

Answer (score 0):

I did small change in your css it works fine for me.,Here is the code below :

**For CSS :**

```
h1{    
    background-color: green;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:7px;
    margin-bottom:6px;
}
h1:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:-7px;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 13px;
    border-image:url("data:image/png;base64,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") 1 1 13 1 repeat;
     background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, -0.2);
    }
```

**For HTML :**

```
<h1>How to get a border image offset from the edge of the box?</h1>

  <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet tenderloin drumstick ribeye filet mignon t-bone beef ribs. Tri-tip venison turkey salami drumstick chicken pastrami. Frankfurter pork jowl ball tip tail.</p>
```

To see it in action : http://jsfiddle.net/john_rock/BDbX2/38/

i think this may help you to resolve your problem.